# ValueError Using a string of single character colors as a color sequence is not supported

Tags: matplotlib

I need help to solve this error, when I run my flask,

> BlockquoteValueError: Using a string of single character colors as a color sequence is not supported. The colors can be passed as an explicit list instead.

```
cat_order = df2.groupby('Category').agg({'App' : 'count'}).rename({'Category':'Total'}, axis=1).sort_values(by='App', ascending=False).head()
X = cat_order.index
Y = cat_order.App
my_colors = 'rgbkymc'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,3),dpi=300)
fig.add_subplot()

plt.barh(X,Y, color=my_colors)

plt.savefig('cat_order.png',bbox_inches="tight")
```

thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post the full error traceback as it shows where the error is originated?

Comment: @Ilhsm were you able to sort this? If so, appreciate if u could post the answer

Comment: @Coder as the asker didn't follow up with the requested full error traceback, the question is left unanswered. However, at first glance, I would say that changing ``'rgbkymc'`` to ``['r', 'g', ...]`` would fix the problem.